# How to get select value in panel heading

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select inside a panel heading which contains the numbers 1-512. These numbers represent a channel.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <select class="channel"></select>
</div>
```

In the panel body I have an input range slider (rangeslider.js).

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <input type="range" class="slider"></input>
</div>
```

Whenever I move the slider, I want to get the value of the slider and the channel number selected in the panel heading. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Jquery code I have so far:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 512; i++)
{
  $('.channel').append($('<option>',
  {
    value: i,
    text: i
  }));
}

$('.slider').rangeslider({
    onSlide: function(position, value) {
      console.log(value);
    }
});
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention this but I have multiple panels so $('.channel').val() would just return the first select's value. When moving the slider I want to get the value of the select which is in the same panel as the slider.

Comment: `console.log($('.channel').val());` this will give you select-box selected value

Comment: So please share more of your code with us. The parent container which contains both `<div class="panel-heading">` and `<div class="panel-body">`. The idea is that you can use the `<div class="panel-body">` parent to get the `<div class="panel-heading">` child. and then access the select element in it...

Answer (score 0):

In the onSlide callback, you can set the value of the select element like

```
$('.slider').rangeslider({
    onSlide: function(position, value) {
      console.log(value);
      $(".channel").val(value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a JSFiddle demonstrating how you can get the value of the slider and change the option box based on the value of the slider:

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/87ocdkLr/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  for (i = 1; i <= 512; i++)
  {
    $('.channel').append($('<option>',
                           {
      value: i,
      text: i
    }));
  }

  $('.slider').change(function() {
    $("select").val($(".slider").val()).change();
  });
});
```